# Excel DGET Criteria double match

Tags: excel

Hi I got a table of data that looks like this:

```
Variable    Value
someVar     UV
someVar1    04-07
```

When using the function DGET(..) on criteria:

```
Variable
someVar
```

I get #NUM! because DGET also finds someVar1.
Is there a way to make search criteria to only find someVar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with by editing the cell like this:

```
="=someVar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in your criteria with something like `=EXACT(A5,$A$2)`.